# Np.mod gives computational artifacts

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I want to check if the behavior of `np.mod` below is correct.

I want to simulate wave propagation through a lens with a focal length `fl_um`. I define a coordinate grid and set the wave-number of the monochromatic light wave. This is just some background info, though.

```
# Make coordinate grid
comp_shape = (2048, 2048)
dx, dy = 8, 8 # in um
fl = 100_000 # in um
wav_num = 2 * np.pi / 0.56 # k-vector

width, height = comp_shape[1], comp_shape[0]
    
xpix = (width - 1) *  np.linspace(-.5, .5, width)
ypix = (height - 1) * np.linspace(-.5, .5, height)
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(dx * xpix, dy * ypix)
```

I know that my lens applies a quaddratic phase shift:

```
def full_paraxial_lens(X, Y, f_um, wavenum_um):
    """ Returns the phase transform done by an ideal lens. 
    
    X: np.array - x input coordinates
    Y: np.array - y input coordinates
    f_um: focal lenght of the lens in microns
    wavenum_um: 2 * pi / lambda in microns
    """
    R2 = X ** 2 + Y ** 2
    return (wavenum_um * f_um - wavenum_um * np.sqrt(R2 + f_um ** 2))
```

When I plot this, everything looks fine:

```
lens_full = full_paraxial_lens(x_grid, y_grid, fl_um, wav_num)
plt.imshow(lens_full)
```

[image]

Now, when I call `np.mod(lens_full, 2 * np.pi)`, I get

```
out = np.mod(lens_full, 2 * np.pi)
plt.imshow(out[824:1224, 824:1224])
```

[image]

Why is this not simply a quadratic term and where do the errors come from?
Can someone explain? Thanks.